# Which method is correct? (generalized additive model, mgcv)

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

If possible could you please let me know if I am on the right track? I don't know anyone who works with GAMs who I can ask and I would be so appreciative of any help I receive. I use mgcv in R.

My data is daily flower counts ('Total'), with different plant genetic lines ('RIL') and 4 different treatments ('Trt'). I basically want to compare the 4 treatments and see if there is a difference in flower production over time between them. Are the shapes of the flowering curves different?

An example of my gam:

```
gam1 <- gam(Total ~ Trt * RIL + s(DateNum, k = 9, bs = "fs") + s(Plant, bs = "re"), data=ce1230)
```

I understand that using anova.gam(gam1) I can see if there is a significant difference between treatments and rils. However when I plot gam1, it shows one curve that represents everything. I was hoping to see a plot with separate curves for each of my 4 treatments. Does this mean that I need to make gamtrt1, gamtrt2, gamtrt3, gamtrt4 and somehow compare the separate gams to each other? or use the original anova(gam1) and just plot each treatment separately? Or am I looking at this the entirely wrong way?

Comment: What is "Plant"?  The reason I ask is that it sounds categorical, in which case a smooth term for it may not be appropriate.

Comment: I had 840 plants in my experiment, so the term Plant was supposed to be for any random effect due to individual plant differences in flower output.

Comment: As you have it structured, the treatment only affects the intercept, not the slope over time.  In order to get an interaction between the `Trt` and the `DateNum` smooth, which is what I suspect you want, I believe you have to add `by=Trt` to the interior of the `s(DateNum,...` smooth term and you will also need to have `Trt` as a factor term independent of `RIL`, i.e., `Total ~ Trt + Trt*RIL + s(DateNum, by=Trt, k=9, bs="fs") + ...`.

Comment: How are you plotting? The help page for `gam` suggests `plot(gam1, pages=1, residuals=TRUE)`, which puts multiple plots on the same output. Without the `pages=1` it should ask you to hit return to see the next plot, are you getting that?

Comment: Also, it only plots the "smoothed" variables; in this model RIL is just a linear term, is that what you want?

Comment: Assuming you want to smooth on `RIL` and make separate smooths, see the 
help on "Specifying generalized additive models"; `?gam.models`, particularly the section on `by` and the corresponding example.

Comment: @jbowman: the `bs="re"` makes it a random effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you want the `by` parameter for `s`.  The resulting set of plots then has one for each level of the `by` factor.  In this example from `?gam.models`, there are three levels of `fac`, so there are three plots for `x2` and one for `x0`.

```
dat <- gamSim(4)
b <- gam(y ~ fac + s(x2, by=fac) + s(x0), data=dat)
plot(b, pages=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for- Adding `by=Trt` in the `s(DateNum)` term gave me a plot for each treatment. Here are my graphs: https://ibb.co/iWvZMy - Hopefully the link works! 
Do you have any insight as to why the GAM fitting my data would make my flower counts (y-axis) become negative? Obviously a plant cannot have -10 flowers. Is there a way to tell the GAM to not be negative? Sorry if these questions sound silly.

Comment: I used this `plot_smooth(gam1, view="DateNum", plot_all="Trt", rm.ranef=TRUE)` from itsadug, and it gave me this graph: https://ibb.co/bP6r1y, which is pretty and allows me to see both treatments on the same graph, but the peak of the graph is different. And it still becomes negative. But it looks more like my data.

Comment: I suppose this might be okay, if I just don't graph the negative portions? https://ibb.co/nKKNPJ

Comment: If negative values are impossible, then your model should reflect that. Don't just hide the parts that don't work for you! A Poisson model (as @AnonymousEmu mentioned) would be worth investigating, or at least log-transforming the response.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try an ANOVA and look at that F-test. If it rejects that, there is evidence that there is variation between treatments. After that, since your outcome if count data, I would do a poisson regression. Unlike GAMs where it can be hard to test the important of effects, Poisson regression gives you your usually p-values which makes it simple to see which things are important to causing the differences in your data.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/

If there is significnet difference between your mean and variance, (poisson says that they should be the same), modify the poisson regression with a Poisson-Gamma model.

Comment: I'm confused... why would switching to a Poisson regression be appropriate? The point of the GAM is to deal with non-linearity, not count data or non-constant variance.

Comment: I didn't read the question fully -- I see now they are counts! Of course a Poisson regression would be worth investigating.

Comment: I'm not sure if a Poisson regression would work as one of the assumptions is that the data needs to have independence of observations, and because I am counting flower production on the same plants each day, flower production on day 3 is not independent of day 2, etc. @Aaron do you still think that this is appropriate?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you be explicit in what ways they would not be independent?

Comment: The number of flowers produced by a plant each day depend on # of flowers the days before due to use of resources by the plant. Flower production in the plant I am studying typically follows a pattern - increase flower production each day until the plant hits peak flower production, then afterwards flower production declines each day as resources are also now being used to mature seeds. Ex: flower counts on plant#10 over 13 days might be 1, 4, 10, 16, 25, 39, 44, 33, 31, 25, 10, 5, 0, (plus perhaps some unpredictable flowering at the end due to treatment effects). And I have 840 plants total.

Comment: Non-independence like that is "independent" (hah!) of whether or not you used a Poisson model. That is, you need to account for the dependence no matter what model you use, even the additive model you were asking about to start with.

Comment: For the gam model, would that mean a term for autocorrelation?

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your data; you can't have a random effect of `Plant` as a factor *and* get the plot you showed in the link in comment to @Aaron's Answer. Are you sure that `Plant` is a factor with more than 1 level? If not, you need to code your data correctly to get a random intercept per plant. Also, can you include both `RIL` and `Plant` level effects? Once you've accounted for the separate `Plant` effects (intercepts), won't that also logically account for the genetic line effects also?

Second, if you are using `bs = 'fs'`, you need to pass in a continuous variable *and* a factor; so far you only pass in `DateNum`. At the moment you have

```
s(DateNum, k = 9, bs = "fs")
```

and I think you wanted

```
s(DateNum, Trt, k = 9, bs = "fs")
```

This model is similar to the one proposed by @Aaron, but is somewhat different in detail. The full model might be

```
gam(Total ~ Trt * RIL + s(DateNum, Trt, k = 9, bs = "fs") + s(Plant, bs = "re"),
    data=ce1230)
```

but I suspect even that is wrong? (For `fs` smooths you don't need the parametric `Trt`.) So I think,

```
gam(Total ~ RIL + Trt:RIL + s(DateNum, Trt, k = 9, bs = "fs") + 
    s(Plant, bs = "re"), data=ce1230)
```

Where the *main* effect of `Trt` is actually contained in the `fs` smooth, so we don't specify it parametrically.

The main difference between this model and @Aaron's in that here, there is a single smoothness parameter for the smooths of `DateNum` by `Trt`, whereas in @Aaron's answer each of the smooths gets it's own smoothness parameter. This boils down to a choice between whether you expect similar wiggliness (the shapes of the smooths can be different) for each smooth or whether you expect some of the four smooths to be a lot wigglier than others?

What you seem to want is interactions between `RIL` and `Trt` plus separate smooths for each `Trt`. But do you want separate smooths for each `RIL` and `Trt` combination? That would require a separate variable formed by the combinations of `RIL` and `Trt` available in your data:

```
ce1230 <- transform(ce1230, 
                    RILTrt = interaction(RIL, Trt, drop = TRUE))
```

And then you could fit

```
gam(Total ~ s(DateNum, RILTrt, k = 9, bs = "fs") + 
    s(Plant, bs = "re"), data=ce1230)
```

or

```
gam(Total ~ s(DateNum, k = 9, by = RILTrt) + 
    s(Plant, bs = "re"), data=ce1230)
```

depending on whether you wanted similar wigliness (use `bs = 'fs'`) or different wigglinesses (use `by`) for each estimated smooth of `DateNum`.

The model also needs to respect the non-negative nature of the response; you have counts and you can't have negative counts of anything. Using `family = poisson` or `family = nb` would be reasonable starting points.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much for this in depth answer. I will try all of these once I get a chance to properly sit down with R. I included the plant term because someone mentioned to me that each plant in my experiment (#1-840) will likely produce flowers slightly different from each other and I needed a term in my model to account for the variation.  So no, plant does not have more than one level. The column 'Plant' in my data sheet is just the label # on that plant's pot. Also the column RIL in my data is categorical - indicates if the plant is one of the several genetic lines I used.

Comment: I basically want to be able to see if the treatments differ and then how the RILs within each treatment vary in their response. I think what I want is closest to the second option you gave me, with separate smooths for each RIL / Treatment combination. Thank you for providing that code to me!  That would be hectic to graph all together, so I'd like to make one more general graph (x= date, y=flower count) with a smooth for each treatment overall, and then a graph for each treatment that shows the response of the RILs within that treatment.

Comment: Even with your new code suggestion and trying family=poisson or family = nb, I am still seeing the same issue with the negative values in the response when I plot(gam). The gam also does not represent the maximum flowers produced either - its almost like the whole curve has been shifted down from where it actually should be. I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: @Sarah `plot.gam` shows the smooths on the scale that they are estimated on (the log scale for `poisson` and `nb` families, by default) and *most importantly* the smooths are subject to a sum-to-zero constraint for identifiability reasons. This constraint centres all the smooths about 0 (to which the intercept gets added to ultimately give predictions). Hence you should see negative values here, and even negative predictions. But once you put predictions on the response scale, through the use of the inverse of the link function, there will be no negative values.

Comment: Hi again Gavin, after a long August of growth chamber experiments, I'm finally able to sit down with the gams again. I followed your advice constructing the gam models with separate smooths for each RIL and Trt combination:
`day1943ce.int <- transform(day1943ce, RILTrt = interaction(RIL, Treatment, drop = TRUE))`
`m3<-gam(Total ~ s(Day, RILTrt, k = 9, bs = "fs"), data=day1943ce.int)`

This gives me the plot: https://paste.pics/27042ec5b88ebde84417e093c22317ef
(I still need to figure out predict.gam to get the data back on the response variable).

Comment: Is there a post hoc test that can tell me which of these curves are significantly different from each other? This graph is the response of flower counts through time after my damage treatment, and it would be nice to know which specific RILTreatment combinations have different responses.

Comment: This is the output for summary(gam)

`Formula: Total ~ s(Day, RILTrt, k = 9, bs = "fs")

Parametric coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept)   -3.446     14.128  -0.244    0.807

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(Day,RILTrt) 86.68    107 33.24  <2e-16 ***

R-sq.(adj) =  0.764   Deviance explained = 78.3%
GCV = 181.54  Scale est. = 166.92    n = 1089`

So sorry for the horrible formatting. I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @Sarah 1: `predict.gam()` has argument `type` which if you set to `"response"` will give you predicted values on the response scale, just don't use the standard errors of the predictions to forma confidence interval on the predictions as it will be wrong. You can always get the correct inverse link function to do any backtransformation to the response scale using `ilink <- family(model)$linkinv`, where `ilink` I now a function you can use to backtransform a vector of predicted values.

Comment: 2: This is possible but will require some tedious coding and will require you to follow the ideas in this [blog post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/) but modify the code there to work with `fs` smoothers. I don't think I have a clear idea how you can compare all pairs of curves *and* correct for doing all those multiple comparisons.

Comment: It has been suggested that simultaneous intervals for all differences be evaluated at once (i.e. we want to expand the standard interval by some amount such that you don't just include 95% of all draws from the posterior distribution of the difference between one pair of curves, but include 95% of posterior draws from the differences of all pairs of curves). This is doable but I'm not aware that anyone has coded this up yet.

3: You can't post code blocks in comments.

Comment: If you have a specific problem re interpreting this model, perhaps as this as a question. Otherwise I doubt we'll get far using comments and Moderators might frown on this - [stats.se] is not a discussion forum. I'd be happy to talk about this more in a chat room here if you want, but I'm travelling until the weekend so I won't be able to chat until early next week. I'm also not promising I can help much with code to do what i said just yet - I have a few other pressing work commitments that I need to attend to.